# Change the indicator on a slider bar after an action

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this current slider bar: http://jsfiddle.net/z68mR/21/

I want the white indicator to move to most right side (value = 10) everytime I check the box. Currently, when I check the box, the displayed value is 10, but the indicator does not move to 10.

This is the JS:

```
window.showValue = showValue;
var refreshIntervalId;
$('#refreshCheck').on('change', function () {
    if($("#refreshCheck").prop("checked")){
                alert("auto refresh on");
                showValue(10);

            }
    else{

                clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
            }
        });

function refresh(time){
                clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
                refreshIntervalId = setInterval(
                    function ()
                    {
    $("#area").text("Refreshed").fadeIn(300).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300).fadeOut(300);
                    }, parseInt(time*1000));    
        }

    /* Refresh timer display */
function showValue(newValue){
            document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=newValue;
            refresh(newValue);

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('input[type=range]').val(10);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z68mR/22/)

And if you want he indicator to be moved both on chech/uncheck just add

```
$('input[type=range]').val(10);
```

and in the `else` statement

[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/z68mR/23/)